# How to use parameters for part of table name in stored procedure in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am creating a procedure in SQL Server 2012 where table name that is created eventually has month and year as part of the table name, for example  `BA_Monthly_Report_Dec_2017`.

This procedure will be run every month and only the last part of the table name will change.

I tried using parameters here but it's not working. Please help.

Comment: Try taking a look at [tag:dynamic-sql].

Comment: If possible, *don't* do that. You're embedding some of your *data* as *metadata*. It's not easy in SQL to create queries that freely mix metadata and data and so *every* query that you write that interacts with these tables will tend to be challenging. You should instead be looking to create a single table and then, *if* data volumes warrant it, look at built in partitioning features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server table names should be defined as static, if the query is static. If you want table name to be dynamic in that case you need to write dynamic query.

You can execute your dynamic query using  `sp_executesql`

In your case you can write your query in SP as following.

```
DECLARE @Month VARCHAR(10) ='Dec'
DECLARE @Year INT = 2017
DECLARE @Query VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Query = 'SELECT * FROM BA_Monthly_Report_' + @Month 
             + '_' + CAST(@Year AS VARCHAR(4))

EXEC sp_executesql @Query
```